# цикл for через list comprehensoins в python 2.7

Tags: циклы, список, python-2.7, генераторы

подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли такую конструкцию записать через list comprehensoins? и как она будет работать
FB - файл с цифрами, с которыми потом надо работать

```
w = open(FB)
for line in w:
d = line.strip().split("\n")
for l in d:
    t = map(int, l.strip().split(","))
    print t
```

Comment: а как числа в файле хранятся, в каждой строчке несколько чисел, разделённых запятой? и хочется получить список списков чисел? тогда может так: `[map(int, line.split(',')) for line in w.lines()]`

Comment: через запятую и пробел *уточнение)

Comment: А вы случайно не CSV пытаетесь читать? Для этого в питоне есть специальная либа `csv`